# How to prevent blogdown from rerendering all posts?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

*Background:*

I am featuring a [blog](https://data-se.netlify.com/) built on @YihuiXie's R package `blogdown`.

*Problem:*

When I `render_site()`, *all* source files (*.Rmd) are rendered - even  the *unchanged* source files are re-reendered.

This complete re-rendering is time consuming and unnecessary (I think).

*Question/ Desired Solution:*

How can I prevent blogdown from re-rendering the unchanged source files? I want blogdown to render only new or changed source files.

*What I have already tried:*

- I've read the [blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/); Yihui seems to propose the ["rebuild-all" approach](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html).
- I've read the help files for `render_site()` and `hugo_build()`. The first one states that it will render all rmd files. In contrast `hugo_build()` does not knit rmd files (ie., rmd files are not compiled to md files).
- I've checked SO and Google, but this question seems not to have been asked before.

*SessionInfo()*:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17    rstudioapi_0.7  knitr_1.20      magrittr_1.5    RcppTOML_0.1.3  xtable_1.8-2    R6_2.2.2        rlang_0.2.0     stringr_1.3.1   tools_3.4.4     xfun_0.1       
[12] miniUI_0.1.1.1  htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.1.19     rprojroot_1.3-2 digest_0.6.15   bookdown_0.7    later_0.7.2     promises_1.0.1  evaluate_0.10.1 mime_0.5        rmarkdown_1.9.4
[23] blogdown_0.6    stringi_1.2.2   compiler_3.4.4  backports_1.1.2 jsonlite_1.5    httpuv_1.4.3   
>
```

Comment: Sounds reaonable. Maybe there's no useful way besides just removing the source files from the folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is on the page you referenced -- [Section 1.7 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html) ("A recommended workflow"). It seems it is not clear enough to you, so let me rephrase it:

1. You should rarely need `bookdown::render_site()`. You can see that I didn't even mention this function in Section 1.7.
2. Use `blogdown::serve_site()`, and it is the *only* function you need to call if your website is published on Netlify, or any servers that can run the `hugo` command to build your website on the server side.
3. If you do not use Netlify, or do not call `hugo` on the server side, but want to build the site locally and publish the `public/` folder manually, call `blogdown::hugo_build()` before you publish your website.

Since you are using Netlify, the answer is basically `blogdown::serve_site()`. That is all you need. It does not re-render Rmd files that have not been changed. See the [Appendix D.3](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html).

Comment: Hi Yihui. What is your workflow recommendation for manually publishing the site onto a shared server? Since I'm not running hugo command on the server side or using Netlify, the only way I know how to create the website is `build_site()` which re-renders all rmd files.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can comment on [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62508839/prevent-re-knitting-of-old-rmd-files-when-publishing-blogdown-website-on-shared) about this

Comment: Did you read Section 1.7 of the blogdown book or the third bullet in my answer?

Comment: Yes I read them both. Build site rehexecutes rmds (but desired for updating iteratively), but your answer to my other question outlines a clear workflow. thanks

Comment: Okay. Good to know that I managed to clarify the expected workflow!

Answer (score 1):

`blogdown::serve_site()` tries to rerender some of my old blog posts after I reset my computer and re-downloaded the code from github.

By using `blogdown:::build_rmds("content/post/{file_name}.Rmd")` I was able to render single Rmd files to html. To check the results I run `hugo server` in the terminal window.