# When using the {blogdown} package, can I exclude certain posts from building?

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I have an R blog with several posts. One of these posts (let's call this one "Post X") contains code that takes very long (several minutes) to complete. (This is a call to `animate()` from the {gganimate} package.)

When I am writing a new post, I'd like to see a preview before deploying the whole blog anew (to Netlify in my case). But I do not want to wait for Post X zu complete every time I'm building the site. (I'm simply using the "Build Website" button in RStudio's "Build" pane.)

But, of course, as soon as I finish the new post, I still want Post X to be included in the blog. What I want is an option that allows me to "skip" building of Post X and use the old files that are already there from the last build (or some other idea I cannot think of right now). I tried setting `draft: true` in the yaml of Post X but it's getting built anyhow.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I now found [How to prevent blogdown from rerendering all posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565439/how-to-prevent-blogdown-from-rerendering-all-posts?rq=1) which basically answers my question. I am leaving this up here in case someone stumbles upon this question first. Feel free to tell me to delete this question.