# Prevent re-knitting of old rmd files when publishing blogdown website on shared server

Tags: ftp, r-markdown, shared-hosting, hugo, blogdown

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565439/how-to-prevent-blogdown-from-rerendering-all-posts) and the `blogdown` documentation, but I can't seem to find a relevant answer for my case.

**EDIT:** I found this blog post describing a workaround using `build_site(method="custom")`. I needed to change a few things (from `md` to `html` in some parts, since the knitted final format is `html` in my case). It seems to work for simple Rmds, but fancy interactive plots requiring `htmlwidgets` don't render correctly.

I recently switched from Wordpress to Hugo and I have a shared server for hosting my website. I'm trying to understand the best workflow to push updates. I'm using `blogdown::build_site()` command to create a publication-ready website, but it re-renders all the old Rmd posts taking extra time. How can I set it up so it only recreates new or edited files? If I was using Netlify route, it would be pretty straightforward due to version control and server-side `hugo` function, but I don't know how to implement a similar solution for self-hosting.

Also in this context, what is a good workflow for dealing with blogdown sites on shared server space? I'm trying to use `WinSCP` FTP synchronization feature, but it needs to compare all the files and takes forever. It is not possible to sync only edited or new files as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I'm repeating [the documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html) and my answer in [the post you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50565439/559676):

1. Do not use `blogdown::build_site()` (again, you rarely need to use this function).
2. Use `blogdown::serve_site()` to (continuously) preview the site.
3. When you are ready to publish the site, run `blogdown::hugo_build()`, and publish the `public/` directory.

I hope it is clear this time.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was confused by serve_site updating the urls for local viewing and thought it will not be fixed by hugo_build. I'll use this approach. Thanks so much for the awesome package!

Comment: It's my great pleasure. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after updating blogdown to 1.14.

`serve_site()` now re-renders all posts since 2015.

It works well downgrading to blogdown 1.10 and hugo 0.87.0

Here's my previous session info before downgrading:

```r
─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 blogdown    * 1.14    2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cachem        1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 callr         3.7.2   2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cli           3.4.1   2022-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 devtools      2.4.4   2022-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 evaluate      0.17    2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 htmltools     0.5.3   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 htmlwidgets   1.5.4   2021-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 httpuv        1.6.6   2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 knitr         1.40    2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 later         1.3.0   2021-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 miniUI        0.1.1.1 2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgbuild      1.3.1   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgload       1.3.0   2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 processx      3.7.0   2022-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 profvis       0.3.7   2020-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 promises      1.2.0.1 2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ps            1.7.1   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 Rcpp          1.0.9   2022-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rlang         1.0.6   2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rmarkdown     2.16    2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rstudioapi    0.14    2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 shiny         1.7.2   2022-07-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 stringi       1.7.8   2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 stringr       1.4.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 urlchecker    1.0.1   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 usethis       2.1.6   2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xfun          0.34    2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 yaml          2.3.6   2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)

 [1] /home/pacha/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2
 [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
 [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
 [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: Just for the record: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/739